# Put the SUM value from the bottom of the page to the top

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

help me,I'm having trouble, I want to bring up the SUM values ​​that I do at the bottom of the page to display to the top, it may seem strange, but I have a table where each row contains a value, and the SUM result of the values ​​will be in the top table.

what i want is

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {{$x}} 
  </td>
</tr>
<br>

  code containing the value $x
```

---

and this is my blade view

```
        @php $no=1; $x= 0;@endphp
    @foreach($maps->m_item as $i)
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 238);"> <td></td><td></td>
        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
        <td>{{$i->item_nama}}</td>
        <td>{{$i->item_satuan}}</td>
        <td>{{$i->item_saldo}}</td>
        <td>{{$i->item_saldo_hargasat}}</td>
        <td>{{$i->item_saldo_nilai}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <!-- JUMLAH ITEM MASUK -->
        <?php
          $jumlah_masuk   = $maps->m_pengadaan_date->where('in_item',$i->item_nama )->sum('in_jumlah');
          $nilai_masuk    = $maps->m_pengadaan_date->where('in_item',$i->item_nama )->sum('in_total');
          $jumlah_keluar  = $maps->m_pengeluaran_date->where('out_item',$i->item_nama )->sum('out_jumlah');
          $jumlah_akhir   = $i->item_saldo + $jumlah_masuk - $jumlah_keluar;

          $hargasat_item  = $maps->m_pengadaan_date->where('in_item',$i->item_nama)->sortByDesc('in_tgl_kwitansi')->pluck('in_hargasat')->last();
                            if($hargasat_item == null){  $hargasat_terakhir = $i->item_saldo_hargasat;  }else{   $hargasat_terakhir = $hargasat_item;}
          $nilai_akhir    = $jumlah_akhir * $hargasat_terakhir;
          $nilai_keluar   = ($nilai_masuk + $i->item_saldo_nilai) - $nilai_akhir;
          $x += $nilai_akhir
   
        ?>
        <td>{{$jumlah_masuk}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{$nilai_masuk}}</td>
        <td></td>

        <td></td>
        <td>{{$jumlah_keluar}}</td>
        <td>{{$nilai_keluar}}</td>
        <td></td>

        <td>{{$jumlah_akhir}}</td>
        <td>{{$hargasat_terakhir}}</td>
        <td>{{$nilai_akhir}}</td>
    </tr>

    
    @endforeach
    <tr>
      <td colspan="19">

      </td>
      <td>
        {{$x}} ssssssss
      </td>
    </tr>
```

---

thank you so much

[Image - I want the white value to appear in the orange column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP6vh.png)

Comment: Make your calculations first (maybe outside of your Blade view), _then_ output the table

Comment: Use javascript / jquery to copy the bottom cell contents to the orange cell after page load.

Comment: @brombeer ,  I have a lot of data, for example A has a value of 1,2,3,4,5, B has a value of 6,7,8,910, before that, every value 1-5 in A has its own sum, if I do it outside Blade maybe I will be confused, especially since I'm new to Laravel, maybe you can help me show a reference or example, thank you very much

Comment: @T.Shah , I will display this data in Laravel Excel, is it possible to use javascript? if you have any documentation or reference please let me know

Comment: Just follow the IPO model ... output _always_ comes last.

Comment: @HonkderHase of course, but placing the result at the top of the BLADE VIEW, is what I was looking for, the result is always at the end but how can it be at the top position

Answer (score 0):

You can include a javascript at the bottom of the above blade file. For that you will have to put @yield('script') just before  tag in your layout file.  Then you can use following code in the above blade file.  I have assigned id 'orange-td' to orange column and the final result td has id called 'td-id'.

```
@section('script')
<script>
    window.onload = function exampleFunction() {
        console.log('The Script will load now.');
        document.getElementById('orange-td').innerHTML = document.getElementById('td-id').innerHTML;
    }
</script>
@endsection
```